# How to reduce LCS from Vertex-Cover

Tags: np-complete

I am trying to understand the demostration of intractability of the LCS problem, as stated as a reduction from Vertex-Cover problem, and so far, i'm stuck with the demostration of the problem in this paper from [David Maier](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=322075)

Anybody know some simple example to reduce LCS from Vertex-Cover?

Comment: nobody knows, everybody downvotes

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It was as simple as:

- Take a Vertex-Cover problem to convert to LCS
- Create a string template from the Vertex-Cover graph
- Take each vertex from the Vertex-Cover problem and generate an equivalent string for it, ommiting the vertex selected
- Presto, you have a LCS problem equivalent.

Thanks for the downvotes